# C# Web API REST Service POST

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I originally asked a question regarding a WCF web service that I was trying to write and then found that the ASP.net web API was more appropriate to my needs, due to some feedback on here.

I've now found a good tutorial that tells me how to create a simple REST service using Web API which works well pretty much out of the box.

**My question**

I have a POST method in my REST service server:

```
    // POST api/values/5
    public string Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
        return "Putting value: " + value;
    }
```

I can POST to this using POSTER and also my C# client code.

However the bit I don't understand is why I have to prepend an '=' sign to the POST data so that it reads: "=Here is my data which is actually a JSON string"; rather than just sending: "Here is my data which is actually a JSON string";

My C# Client that talks to the REST service is written as follows:

```
 public string SendPOSTRequest(string sFunction, string sData)
    {
        string sResponse = string.Empty;

        // Create the request string using the data provided
        Uri uriRequest = GetFormRequest(m_sWebServiceURL, sFunction, string.Empty);
        // Data to post
        string sPostData = "=" + sData;
        // The Http Request obj
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uriRequest);
        request.Method = m_VERB_POST;
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        Byte[] byteArray = encoding.GetBytes(sPostData);
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        request.ContentType = m_APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED;                

        try
        {
            using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            }
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
                    sResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }                    
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
             //Log exception
        }

        return sResponse;
    }

    private static Uri GetFormRequest(string sURL, string sFunction, string sParam)
    {
        StringBuilder sbRequest = new StringBuilder();
        sbRequest.Append(sURL);

        if ((!sURL.EndsWith("/") &&
            (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sFunction))))            
        {
            sbRequest.Append("/");
        }
        sbRequest.Append(sFunction);

        if ((!sFunction.EndsWith("/") && 
            (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sParam))))
        {
            sbRequest.Append("/");
        }
        sbRequest.Append(sParam);

        return new Uri(sbRequest.ToString());
    }
```

Is anybody able to explain why I have to prepend the '=' sign as in the above code (`string sPostData = "=" + sData;`)?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Whay don't you use something like restsharp for this? http://restsharp.org/

Comment: @KosalaW http://i.imgur.com/ybWKjSM.png :D

Comment: Hi Kosala W, thanks for this. To be honest I didn't look at this but maybe I should have. My job is to write the client code that interfaces with the server code which will ultimately be written by a third party. I just need to provide a test harness and guidance of the API..

With this in mind do you have any feedback on the above as prepending an '=' sign to the POST data seems wrong but if I have to then I will I would just like to understand a bit more?

Thanks

Comment: you're using m_APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED; for your body.  That's key value pairs of data, which is the reason for =.  if you want to try out sending data to your api you can try using some of the tools like postman, fiddler etc.

Comment: Ah I see which is my const of "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

What should I use if I wish to simply POST the data without key value pair?

Thanks

Comment: try application/json and post the javascript object that represents your data

Comment: Thanks but if I do this the REST Service [FromBody]string value is null.

The data i'm trying to post is a JSON string?
I can't POST the javascript object because there isn't one. My client is a C# desktop APP that uses JavaScriptSerializer to serialise my class into a JSON string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content type `x-www-form-urlencoded` is a key-value format. With form bodies you are only able to read a single simple type from a request body. As a name is expected, but in this case not allowed, you have to prefix the equal sign to indicate that there is no name with the followed value.

However, you should lean away from accepting simple types within the body of your web-api controller actions.

You are limited to only a single simple type if you attempt to pass data in the body of an HttpPost/HttpPut without directly implementing your own MediaTypeFormatter, which is unlikely to be reliable. Creating a light-weight complex type is generally much more preferable, and will make interoperating with other content-types, like `application/json`, much easier.

Comment: Hey Jonathon, Great thank you for this explanation it clears things up for me. Now that I understand why, I can have a think about the best way to solve the issue within my constraints. I take on board what you say about using simple types. Thanks again!